# returning an empty json even though it's not empty

Tags: reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to return a json to a my react client, with a list of songs (objects). But it returns an empty array as a json. This is how I retrieve the data.

```
let songs = [];
  fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + req.user.accessToken
    },
    json: true
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(apiResponse => {
      let limit = apiResponse.limit;
      for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        Song.findOrCreate({
          where: {
            name: apiResponse.items[i].track.name,
            song_spotify_id: apiResponse.items[i].track.id,
            album: apiResponse.items[i].track.album.name,
            popularity: apiResponse.items[i].track.popularity,
            track_number: apiResponse.items[i].track.track_number,
            uri: apiResponse.items[i].track.uri
          }
        }).then(song => {
          songs.push(song);
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      return {
        type: "ERROR ON FETCH",
        api_response: { success: false }
      };
    });

  console.log("songs: *********************" + songs);
  res.status(200).json(songs);
});
```

This is my react api fetch:

```
const requestMySongs = async () => {
  const data = await fetch("/mysongs").catch();
  console.log(data);
  const jsoned = await data.json();
  console.log(jsoned);
  let five = [];
  // only 5 songs
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    five.push(jsoned[i]);
  }
  console.log(five);
  return five;
};
```

When I console log jsoned, it appears the following:

```
[]
```

What's weird, is that I had two versions. One version is this one, that requests the spotify api for only 20 songs. My other version is almost exactly the same, only that it loops and asks for the whole list of songs (gets 50, saves 50, requests spotify for another 50, and so on), and this other version works. The code is exactly the same, but the problem was that it was taking to long to load, so I tried to simplify it, but it's not working.

I appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have to wait all the promises before sending your response.

Actually you send the response, but the process to query inside your database is not running yet.

```
let songs = [];
  fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + req.user.accessToken
    },
    json: true
  })
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(apiResponse => {
      let limit = apiResponse.limit;
      let promises = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Song.findOrCreate({
          where: {
            name: apiResponse.items[i].track.name,
            song_spotify_id: apiResponse.items[i].track.id,
            album: apiResponse.items[i].track.album.name,
            popularity: apiResponse.items[i].track.popularity,
            track_number: apiResponse.items[i].track.track_number,
            uri: apiResponse.items[i].track.uri
          }
        }).then(song => {
          songs.push(song);
          resolve(true)
        });
        });

        promises.push(myPromise);
      }

      Promise.all(promises)
      .then(() => {
          console.log("songs: *********************" + songs);
          res.status(200).json(songs);
      });

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      return {
        type: "ERROR ON FETCH",
        api_response: { success: false }
      };
    });

});
```